# Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility client on Ubuntu 20.04 with SAML/SSO does not show the page for authentication

Tags: networking, 20.04, vpn, cisco

I have a Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility client on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

The process is, start the client/vpn and then wait for the authentication screen/page (SAML/SSO) to ingress with mail/pass.

But the screen no longer appears, showing only the message:
"Please Complete the Authentication Process in the Browser Window"

The log shows this:

```
Authentication process in the browser window.
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acvpnui[22948]: Function: IsValid File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/VerifyFileSignatureOpenSSL.cpp Line: 341 Code-signing verification succeeded. File (/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/acextwebhelper)
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acwebhelper[26619]: Function: main File: ../../../vpn/ExternalBrowserHelper/ExternalBrowserHelper.cpp Line: 60 AnyConnect External Web Browser Helper started with command line of '60115'
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acwebhelper[26619]: Function: initIpc File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC-JSON/JSONIPCClient.cpp Line: 167 Initiating IPC connection to 127.0.0.1:60115...
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acwebhelper[26619]: Function: handleConnect File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC-JSON/JSONIPCClient.cpp Line: 203 IPC connection established
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acvpnui[22948]: Function: Start File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC-JSON/JSONIPCConn.cpp Line: 56 Accepted IPC connection #9 from client
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acwebhelper[26619]: Function: OnBrowserResultSendComplete File: ../../../vpn/ExternalBrowserHelper/ExternalBrowserSSOController.cpp Line: 274 OnBrowserResultSendComplete
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acvpnui[22948]: Function: launchBrowser File: ../../../vpn/WebHelper/Plugin/WebHelperPluginImpl.cpp Line: 744 Browser process launched successfully [pid 26619]
Mar 21 09:56:55 NOTE001 acwebhelper[26622]: Function: Launch File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/ProcessAPI_unix.cpp Line: 401 Invoked Function: execvp Return Code: 2 (0x00000002) Description: unknown No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu is up to date, I already installed the customer and browsers but has no effect.

The version of the client is 4.10.05085.

Comment: Yes I tested. By researching this client/vpn uses chrome as default, but even removing and leaving Firefox it behaved the same. And, I didn't find how to change this default browser.

Comment: Changing the default browser shouldn't be necessary for testing. The last line of the pasted output says the file `ProcessAPI_unix.cpp` is not found. Since this file has the word `unix` in it, I assume it is needed only for accessing the web page from an Unix or Linux computer. My guess is, someone at the web server management decided they don't need "Unix" support and deleted this file.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution was to use Firefox.

But, Firefox home need to be */usr/bin/firefox*. If you made installation by SNAP, do you need to remove it.

If you want to clean everything related to Firefox follow this process:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
cd ;
sudo rm -rf .mozilla
cd /etc
sudo rm -rf firefox
cd /usr/lib/
sudo rm -rf firefox-addons
sudo apt install firefox
```

If not, just run:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```